# Одинаковые значения $(document).height() и $(window).height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

В силу определенных обстоятельств, пытаюсь написать скрипт (знаю, что обычно это делают с помощью стилей, но в моем случае стили были написаны до меня и ни один из примеров, найденных в Google не подходит, потому что если начинаю менять параметры стили `body` и т.д., верстка падает), для того, чтобы прибить `footer` к низу страницы (на тех страницах, где маленький контент-блок).

Нашел неплохое решение:

```
$(document).ready(function func() {
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).height()) {
        console.log('snuggle func!');
        $("footer").addClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
    }
});
```

На коротких страницах все хорошо - footer приклеивается к низу страницы. Однако на больших страницах скрипт также подкидывает в footer `"navbar-fixed-bottom"`(хотя по идее так быть не должно). В console.log при загрузке `$(document).height()` и `$(window).height()` одинаковые, что странно. Вбил в консоли разработчиков эти команды и только тогда получил нормальные значения (разумеется на больших страницах `$(document).height()` >  `$(window).height()`). Тем не менее скрипт выдает при загрузке страницы одинаковые значения.

Почему так происходит? И как можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: а чем должны отличаться _$(**document**).height() и $(**document**).height()_???

Comment: А вы уверены что всё правильно делаете? Если у вас на сайте нет прокрутки страницы (страница помещается в окно, то значения буду одинаковые.. Или же попробуйте брать высоту с *body*

Comment: @Grundy речь идет о document и window, а не о document и document. отличия window.height и document.height:
// Returns height of browser viewport
$( window ).height();
 
// Returns height of HTML document
$( document ).height();

Comment: @Iga, у вас в заголовке было написано document и document ))

Comment: @Yuri нет, не уверен,поэтому и получаю не совсем тот эффект,который ожидал и не понимаю почему так.в том-то и дело,что на некоторых страницах со скроллом он рисует одинаковую высоту,но стоит в консоли проверить, и видны другие значения.попробую ориентироваться по body

Comment: @Yuri пардон муа,опечатался)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если контент отрисовывается после выполнения сего кода, то код сначало добавит класс, потом отобразит "длинный" контент (а класс то никто уже не удалит).

Думаю разумнее сделать функцию

```
function updateFooterClass() {
   $("footer").toggleClass("navbar-fixed-bottom", $(document).height() <= $(window).height());
}
```

и вызывать её не только по $(document).ready() но и по каким-то событиям обновления контента. На крайний случай

```
(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(updateFooterClass, 1000);
});
```

Comment: вы правы,пробелмы в том,что некоторое содержимое не сразу прогружается и скрипт отрабатывает первее. ваше решение рабочее,также с этим вроде справляется window.onload